# scala duplicate elements in list

Tags: scala, list-comprehension

I need to duplicate every element in a list.
Here is what I came up with for that:

```
List.range(1,5).map(i => List(i,i)).flatten
```

which outputs

```
List[Int] = List(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4)
```

I wonder whether this is the most efficient way to do that (ultimately it needs to run on a lot of data), given that for every element, a new list would be created.

(the above is on an int range, to keep the example simple)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you need to duplicate every element in the list, in the first place?

Comment: actually, I need to apply two different functions on each of the elements. The efficiency question would be the same as with duplication.

Comment: Is the order of the elements important?

Comment: yes, since additionally there would be a filter whether f1(i) > f2(i), for the two functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A more general solution would be something like:

```
def duplicate[T](list: List[T]): List[T] = list.flatMap(x => List[T](x, x))
```

Using immutable collections won't be all that efficient for very large data sets. A simple implementation using the mutable `ListBuffer` is already 10 times faster than the above (using a list with one million elements):

```
def duplicate[T](list: List[T]): List[T] = {

    val buffer = collection.mutable.ListBuffer[T]()

    list.foreach{ x =>
        buffer += x
        buffer += x
    }

    buffer.toList
}
```

This uses a general technique of appending to a `ListBuffer` for performance, then converting to the immutable `List` at the end.

Comment: I understand that. My question is about the efficiency of creating and flattening an additional list for every element in the original list.

Comment: Is it a general approach using auxiliary mutable collections when dealing with performance?

Answer (score 6):

Do you really need lists? can you do better by being more generic? Lists are often over-used when other collections can be much better suited. Here's a method which takes any Seq and creates a Stream which duplicates the items, Streams are naturally lazy, You won't necessarily have the memory overhead of creating and throwing away a lot of little lists:

```
def dupe[A](as: Seq[A]): Stream[A] = as match { 
  case Seq(h, t @ _*) => h #:: h #:: dupe(t)
  case _ => Stream.empty 
}
```

We can see that it acts lazily:

```
scala> dupe(List(1,2,3,4))
res1: Stream[Int] = Stream(1, ?)
```

Lazily enough that it works in very large or even infinite input:

```
scala> dupe(Stream.range(1, Int.MaxValue)).take(10).force
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5)

scala> dupe(Stream.continually(1)).take(10).force
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

if you really want a list:

```
scala> dupe(List(1,2,3,4)).toList
res5: List[Int] = List(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4)
```

Comment: The `toList` at the end comes at a huge cost, though.

Comment: @LimbSoup yes, this is true, I was predicating this answer on "perhaps you don't need lists all the time" though.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution:
Parameter times means how many times do you want repeat each element in the list

```
def repeatElementsInList[T](list: List[T],times: Int): List[T] = {
       list.flatMap (x =>
         List.fill(times)(x)
       )
   }

scala> repeatElementInList(List("a",1,"b"),3)
res6: List[Any] = List(a, a, a, 1, 1, 1, b, b, b)
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation with your code, so the OP can learn from it.

Answer (score 2):

And yet another version

```
def dupe[T](xs:List[T]):List[T] = 
    xs.foldRight(List[T]()) {(elem, acc) => elem::elem::acc}
```

Probably about as efficient as the map, but saves an extra iteration over the list for the flatten

Answer (score 1):

why not

```
var a = List("a","b","c")

val c = a ::: a

println(c)
```

Comment: Hey there! Generally, answers are more useful when they include an explanation of what the code does. Otherwise your answer may be deleted. Please keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Following comments above, for any given methods such as `f1(x: Int): Int` and `f2(x: Int): Int`, consider

```
(1 to 5).par.filter { x => f1(x) > f2(x) }
```

where `par` casts the range onto a parallel collection, worth considering for large collections.

Comment: yes, that's what I left out to keep the example simple